# Eigenvalue calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In my textbook it is said that

> $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ is eigen value of matrix A iff $det(\lambda I-A)=0$

However in solved problems I saw it computed as $det(A-\lambda I)=0$. This confuses me, why is it different? (Hopefully I translated the terminology correctly)

Comment: It is basically the same thing. The eigenvalues are the solutions of the characteristic polynomial, which by definition is $\text{det}(A-\lambda I)=: f(x)$. Evaluating $\text{det}(\lambda I -A)$ you get $-f(x)$. But both $f(x)$ and $-f(x)$ have the same roots. Indeed let $\lambda_1$ be a root for $f(x)$ then $f(\lambda_1) = 0 = -0 = -f(\lambda_1)$

Comment: @Ale Oh, thank you for explaining, that's what bothered me, I thought I would get solution with opposite sign. If you post it as answer I would accept it.

Comment: no problem. I prefer not to answer (I will post it as an answer in a few days maybe) because someone else could have a better explanation than mine. But however I'm glad it helped you ;). Personally I prefer to evaluate $\text{det}(\lambda I - A)$ because it is easier, for me, to evaluate the determinant, but it is a matter of tastes. (It avoids confusions and reduces the possibility of errors due to the $-$ sign.